# How to Add div right below to the input text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to develop my simple autocomplete, I'm not interested in the JQuery autocomplete Plugin.

I just want to add a dive right below the input text, this code was suppose to work, what am I doing wrong? what is the way to accomplish that?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uZF5g/)

here is the code if you don't whant to open fiddle:

```
$("#txtSearch").keypress(function (e) {
    if ($("#txtSearch").val().length >= 2) {
        var pos = $("#txtSearch").position();
        $('<div />', {
            'html': "xxxxxxxxx  xx  x"
        }).css({
            top: pos.top,
            left: pos.left,
            width: '300px',
            position: 'absolute',
            'background-color': 'Yellow'
        }).appendTo($("#txtSearch"));
    }
});
```

Comment: Inside the event handler, you can use `$(this)` instead of going back to the DOM to find the element again (and again and again).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below code,

```
$("#txtSearch").keypress(function (e) {
   if ($("#txtSearch").val().length >= 2) {
      var pos = $("#txtSearch").position();
      $('<div />')
      .html("xxxxxxxxx  xx  x")
      .css({
         top: pos.top + $("#txtSearch").height()  + 1,
         left: pos.left,
         width: '300px',
         position: 'absolute',
         'background-color': 'Yellow'
      }).insertAfter($("#txtSearch"));
   }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/uZF5g/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can't append to (`.appendTo`) empty content model elements.  Use `.insertAfter` (or `.insertBefore`) instead.  You probably also want the `top` to at least be added to the height of the input.

http://jsfiddle.net/uZF5g/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#txtSearch").keypress(function (e)
 {
    if ($("#txtSearch").val().length >= 2)
    {
    $('#txtSearch').after('<div id="someID">');
    $('#someID').html('xxxxxxx xx x')
       .css({ 
             top: pos.top, 
             left: pos.left, 
             width: '300px', 
             position: 'absolute', 
             'background-color': 'Yellow' 
           })
       .appendTo($("#txtSearch"));  
    }
 });
```